# En el problema me piden que "no reciba parámetros ni devuelva valor" y eso me confunde

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda!! espero me puedan ayudar. En el ejercicio 1 me pidió escribir un programa para que, mediante una función permita, dado un *string*, retornar la longitud de la última palabra. Pero en el segundo me pidió escribir una solución para el ejercicio anterior, pero esta vez con un procedimiento que no  reciba parámetros ni devuelva valor, con acceso a variables de entrada y resultado del programa principal.

Entonces no entiendo que estaría dando en el segundo ejercicio, además que me sale "no  reciba parámetros ni devuelva valor", lo cual me hace confundir. Un compañero me dijo que en este código tenia que usar un *"global"* pero tampoco se en que parte colocarlo.

les dejo el código que utilice en el primer ejercicio:

```py
def longitud(str):

    Cuenta = 0;
    flag = False;
    longitud = len(str)-1;
    while(longitud != 0):
        if(str[ longitud] == ' '):
            return Cuenta;
        else:
            Cuenta += 1;
        longitud -= 1;
    return Cuenta;

#obtener el resultado
str = input("Escriba una frase:  ")
print("la ultima longitud de frase es: ", longitud(str));
```

Gracias por leerme!! y perdón lo perdida!

Comment: el enunciado parece ambiguo. Lo interpreto de 2 maneras: A) Usas variables dentro del código que se "autollenen" y no le pides nada al usuario, o simplemente haces que no reciba ninguna entrada y no de ninguna salida, pero eso no tiene mucho sentido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te ayudo solo por que veo que estas muy confundida y que recién estas empezando. Primero hay que aclarar que estas usando la palabra `str` como una variable y `str` es una palabra reservada en Python. Ahora procedemos a la explicacion

1. Dices que hay que hacer una función que retorne la longitud de la ultima palabra

Para hacer esto, hacemos una función, en este caso la voy a llamar `longitud()`, la cual recibirá un parámetro que será la frase, luego tenemos que hallar la longitud de la ultima palabra, ¿y como hacemos eso?, pues sabemos que una palabra empieza cuando hay un espacio al final o delante de esta, para eso utilizamos el método `split()` para separar la palabra por cada espacio que tenga, esto nos retornara una lista, y para saber acceder a la ultima palabra podemos hacerlo con `[-1]`, ya que como es una lista podemos acceder a sus elementos y al poner `-1` le decimos que queremos el ultimo elemento y finalmente sacamos su longitud con `len()`

```py
def longitud(texto):
    texto = texto.split()#separamos cada palabra
    longitud = len(texto[-1])#obtenemos la longitud de la ultima
    return longitud #retornamos la ultima
```

Al tener esto ya es fácil hacer una función que no reciba algún parámetro. Y como dices si hay que decláralo como una variable *global* pues esto tiene que ver con el *scope* de una variable. primero declaramos una variable llamada `texto` y luego otra `longitud` dentro de la función.

```py
global texto 
texto = input("Ingrese una frase: ")

def longitud2():
    global longitud
    texto2 = texto.split()
    longitud = len(texto2[-1])
```

Y listo solo tendremos que llamar a la función.

```py
longitud2()
print(longitud)
```

Pero por que declaramos la variable en la función? pues esto es por el escope de una función pues las variables existen solo dentro de la función, por lo que si hacemos `global longitud` fuera de la función no servirá y te dará un error diciendo que la variable no esta definida